# How to get the result of intersect function not in a string format in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I use intersect function in Matlab. I have two excel columns of names and I want to get their intersect. Now, the problem is the result is in string format (i.e. 'Sara'. I don't want the string sign '', I just need the name (i.e. Sara). The result is several hundred and I can't delete them manually.

I write like this format:

```
[num,txt1,raw] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx','Sheet1','A2:A3000'));
[num,txt2,raw] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx','Sheet1','B2:B2500'));
A = intersect (txt1, txt2);
```

The excel file has no problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Please be more specific and include a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem is probably in how you import the data from Excel, not in using `intersect`.

Comment: I think what you want is the `categorical` function

Comment: Thank you so much, @Sardar. I used this function and the problem is solved.